# Branching solution

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, branch, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

I'm working with visual studio and TFS and currently exploring the idea of branching and merging.  To give a general overview of how I'm organizing one solution:

```
MySolution
-  MyProject 1
   MyProject1TestBranch
-  MyProject 2
-  MyProject 3
```

I have been playing around with this and created a test branch and have been testing merging changes between "MyProject 1" and "MyProject1TestBranch".

Is it a good idea to be merging individual projects in a solution like this?  What if several projects share code from another project?  OR should I be branching the entire solution to keep it simple?

If it's best to branch an entire solution, what are the advantages / disadvantages of doing so?  Should I perhaps be looking at using a completely different strategy entirely?

Appreciate any feedback.  I guess at this stage I'm just looking for some verification as to whether or not I'm heading in the right direction

Comment: Grow more and more tired of this community.  Essentially no point at all in posting for fear of being ridiculed for inviting opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are usually links between projects within one solution, therefore I think create different branches within the same solution would make more problem then benefit, as you cannot reference your projects to the solution properly.

I would suggest you, to create branch from a unit, which has it's own application lifecycle (I usually call it "product"). And if it depends on other projects/solution, then handle it as an "external" dependency.

For branching strategies I can suggest the below articles:

- https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/branching-strategies-with-tfvc
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_(version_control)
- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.whatis.html
- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.commonpatterns.html

On the other hand, creating a branch itself in most version control system does not require storage, so you cannot really save anything on creating branches from sub-products / projects.